# $L(V,\mathbb{R})$ with $\|\cdot\|_1$ complete?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $(V,\|\cdot\|_V)$ and $(W,\|\cdot\|_W)$ be normed vector spaces. By $L(V,W)$ we denote the space of bounded linear operators from $V$ to $W.$ If $W$ is complete, then $L(V,W)$ with the operator norm $\|T\| := \sup \left\{\|Tu\|_W : \|u\|_V \leq 1\right\}$ is a Banach space.

Now assume in addition that $\gamma$ is probability measure on $V$ with $\mathrm{supp}\, \gamma = V$ and with existing first moment.

My Question: Is $L(V,\mathbb{R})$ closed subspace in $(\mathrm{L}_1(V),\|\cdot\|_1)$?

In this case $L(V,\mathbb{R})$ with $\|\cdot\|_1$ would also be a Banach space.

Comment: do you define $\Vert f \Vert_1:=\Vert f \Vert + \Vert f' \Vert$? What is $L_1(V)$?

Comment: $\mathrm{L}_1(V)$ denotes the usual Lebesgue space that contains all measurable $f : V \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$ \|f\|_1 := \int_V |f(v)| \, \gamma(\mathrm{d}v) < \infty$$

Comment: @H17 The norm on $L(V,\mathbb{R})$ is irrelevant, right?

Comment: @H17 Also, there is a technicality that is bothering me. $L_1(V)$ consists of equivalence classes of functions whereas $L(V,\mathbb{R})$ consists of genuine functions. So, I don't really view $L(V,\mathbb{R})$ as a subset of $L_1(V)$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! We may identify a function in $L(V,\mathbb{R})$ with its equivalence class in $\mathrm{L}_1(V).$

Comment: Yes, actually the operator norm on $L(V,\mathbb{R})$ is irrelevant.

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean by "existing first moment". Wouldn't we need to fix a random variable first to be able to talk about first moments? I am sorry if I am missing something elementary, I do not know much about probability.

Comment: We do not need to fix a random variable first. A k-th moment of a probability measure $P$ (on a Banach space) is said to exist if $$\int \|x\|^k \, P(\mathrm{d} x) < \infty$$

Comment: And what is $P(dx)$?

Comment: The integral is the Lebesgue-Integral. And $P(\mathrm{d}x)$ means that we integrate with respect to the probability measure $P$ on the Banach space. Here, $x$ just denotes the elements in this Banach space.

Comment: Great, thanks. Then I will include that in my answer.

Comment: So essentially we do fix a random variable, namely $x\rightarrow \Vert x \Vert^k$. Is there such a construction for a general measure space?

Comment: Actually the random variable (construction) is just the identity $x \mapsto x.$ Random variables are very useful to work with (describing events etc ...). However, in probability theory the interesting object is actually the probability measure. Random variables are in fact rarely necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. Consider $V=l^2(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{R})$ and let $e_i$ be the i-th basis vector of the usual Schauder basis. Set
$$ \gamma = \sum_{n\geq 1} 2^{-n} \delta_{e_n}$$
And consider the following sequence of bounded linear functionals
$$l_m (x) = \sum_{j=1}^m j \cdot x_j $$
This forms a Cauchy sequence as for $m>k$ holds
$$ \Vert l_m - l_k \Vert = \sum_{j=k+1}^m j\cdot 2^{-j}$$
I leave it to you to you to show that this sequence does not converge to some bounded operator (assume it does and then do the computation for the norm to get a contradiction).

**Added:** I forgot to check that my probability measure admits the first moment (I did not even know how it was defined, thanks to H17 for telling me). In fact not only does the first moment exist, but all moments do. Indeed, for $k\geq 1$ we have
$$ \int \Vert x \Vert^k \gamma(dx) = \sum_{n\geq 1} \Vert e_n \Vert^k \cdot 2^{-n}
= \sum_{n\geq 1} 2^{-n} = 1. $$